# On worker 2: UndefVarError (julia) - Variable defined within an if-else statement

Tags: julia

I noticed that running a function within a `@sync @parallel for` loop is problematic if the argument of this function is defined within an if-else statement.

**Example 1**: It doesn't work

```
@everywhere function test_fun(arg)
    println(arg);
end

flag = 1;

if flag == 1
    asd = 123;

    @sync @parallel for i=1:10
        test_fun(asd);
    end
end
```

**Example 2**: It works

```
@everywhere function test_fun(arg)
    println(arg);
end

asd = 123;

@sync @parallel for i=1:10
    test_fun(asd);
end
```

`@everywhere asd = 123;` fixes the problem for the examples defined above, but it doesn't work when you define a SharedArray:

**Example 3**: It doesn't work with @everywhere asd

```
@everywhere function test_fun(arg)
    println(arg);
end

flag = 1;

if flag == 1
    @everywhere asd = 123;
    arr = SharedArray{Float64}(asd);

    @sync @parallel for i=1:10
        test_fun(arr);
    end
end
```

Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please report the errors? Copy-paste of your codes works under Julia 0.6.2 for me.

Comment: I am using Julia 0.5.2 with 2 workers. The error message is in the title. Can it be something that has been fixed with 0.6.2?

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6760 is the same issue. You can take a look at the reference issues, as well. Probably, it is not fixed in your version.